# Angular-Material tabs adapted to work as wizard

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have found how to add the next and previous button functionality and have implemented it as such: http://plnkr.co/edit/iNEXWXUBDvsrKgUSelkW?p=preview

```
          $scope.nextTab = function() {
        var index = ($scope.selectedIndex == $scope.max) ? 0 : $scope.selectedIndex + 1;
        $scope.selectedIndex = index;

        if(!$scope.carinfo.$valid) alert('it has errors');
}
```

However I need an optimal way of preventing the user from switching to the next tab/step if the form in the current tab is not valid. I am able to do this when user clicks on the next/previous buttons by simply checking if the $valid variable bound to the form state or if the form has ng-invalid class attached. However not sure what the best way to go would be to implement such blocking behaviour when the user switches tabs not by clicking on the 'next' and 'previous' buttons I have added, but on the actual tab itself.

Comment: When you update scope.selectedIndex that switches the tab, right? Why not just wrap that in a conditional statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a callback for `<md-tab>` that you can hook into called `md-on-select`.

Source: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdTab

Wouldn't you be able to do the same logic in that callback?

OR maybe you could disable tabs you don't want the user to switch to, using `md-active` flag

Comment: What would you fire on md-on-select though to abort the transition ? I probably could check the form in the previous tab content for the ng-invalid flag using jquery or its $valid state and switch back to said tab, but something tells me there must be a more practical way of doing it.

Comment: Can't you disable those tabs so that users can't even click on them?